# Linux Script to selectively kill processes

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking at a way to automate the following:

1. Run `ps -ef` to list all processes.
2. Filter out those rows containing `java` in the `CMD` column.
3. Filter out those rows containing `root` in the `UID` column.
4. For each of the filtered rows, get the `PID` column and run `pargs <PID>`.
5. If the output of `pargs <PID>` contains a particular string `XYZ`, the issue a `kill -9 <PID>` command.

To filter out rows based on specific column values, is there a better way than `grep`? I can use

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $1}' | grep <UID>
```

but then I lose info from all other columns. The closest thing I have right now is:

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep root | grep -v grep | xargs pargs | ?????
```

### EDIT

I was able to solve the problem by using a using the following script:

```
ps -ef | awk '/[j]ava/ && /root/ {print $2}' | while read PID; do
    pargs "$PID" | grep "Args" > /dev/null && kill -9 $PID && echo "$PID : Java process killed!"
done
```

both `anubhava`'s and `kojiro`'s answers helped me reach there. But since I can only accept one answer, I tagged `kojiro`'s answer as the correct one since it helped me a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -U 0 java | while read pid; do
    pargs "$pid" | grep -qF XYZ && kill "$pid"
done
```

`pgrep` and `pkill` are available on many Linux systems and as part of the "proctools" packages for *BSDs and OS X.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce all `grep` by using `awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk '/[j]ava/ && /root/ {print $1}' | xargs pargs
```

Searching for pattern `/[j]ava/` will skip this `awk` process from output of `ps`.

You can also use `pkill` if it is available on your system.